# Django Model Field Validation

Tags: django-models, django-2.1

I have a model

```
class StudentBasicInfo(models.Model):
    usn = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=10,unique=True,validators=[])
```

my usn will be in format [0-9][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]

I don't know how to write validation code

Answer (score 0):

create a validator. I'd suggest a RegexValidator like so:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

...

class StudentBasicInfo(models.Model):
    usn = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=10,unique=True, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='[0-9][A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}', message='Error message goes here')])
```

I took the liberty of shortening your regex by combining groups that were together. If you want to make the error appear next to the field in the admin you'll have to overload a ModelForm.